# ASA 5505 outside access for clients with dynamically assigned IPs, no outside access for clients with static IPs

Tags: cisco, dhcp, nat, cisco-asa, dnat

We have an ASA configured to access the internet, which works fine for clients who have an IP address assigned by DHCP, but not for clients with manually assigned IPs.

For instance, with the DHCP server configured to give IP addresses between 172.16.101.1 and 172.16.101.10, a device may get the IP address 172.16.101.1. This machine will have connectivity to the internet.

If we then configure DHCPd server range as 172.16.101.2 to 172.16.101.10 and statically assign the 172.16.101.1 IP to the client, it will not have internet access. It will, however have inside access and VPN access.

If I try to ping 8.8.8.8, the following is logged:

> ASA 3  Feb 08 2013  15:51:01  8.8.8.8  xxx.xxx.xxx.100    Deny inbound
>   icmp src    outside:8.8.8.8    dst    servers:xxx.xxx.xxx.100 (type 0,
>   code 0)

Where 'servers' is the name of the inside interface the request is made from and 'xxx.xxx.xxx.100' is the external IP. It seems as DNAT is not working when the client IP is static assigned.

Has anybody seen this behaviour before? It has me stumped!

The running config:

```
ASA Version 8.2(5)

!

hostname hayes-fw

enable password XXXXXXXXX encrypted

passwd XXXXXXXXX encrypted

names

name 212.xxx.xxx.2 DUNSTABLE

!

interface Ethernet0/0

description Internet

switchport access vlan 105

switchport trunk allowed vlan 100,109

switchport trunk native vlan 999

switchport mode trunk

speed 100

duplex full

!

interface Ethernet0/1

description Failover back-to-back

switchport access vlan 254

!

interface Ethernet0/2

description Internal

switchport trunk allowed vlan 100-106

switchport trunk native vlan 999

switchport mode trunk

speed 100

duplex full

!

interface Ethernet0/3

description unused

switchport trunk allowed vlan 100-104

!

interface Ethernet0/4

description temp-inside

switchport trunk allowed vlan 60

switchport trunk native vlan 60

switchport mode trunk

!

interface Ethernet0/5

description unused

switchport access vlan 253

shutdown

!

interface Ethernet0/6

description unused

switchport access vlan 253

shutdown

!

interface Ethernet0/7

description unused

switchport access vlan 100

!

interface Vlan60

nameif temp-inside

security-level 100

ip address 172.xx.60.253 255.255.255.0

!

interface Vlan100

description Mgmt

nameif mgmt

security-level 100

ip address 172.xx.100.253 255.255.255.0 standby 172.16.100.252

!

interface Vlan101

nameif servers

security-level 90

ip address 172.16.101.253 255.255.255.0 standby 172.16.101.252

!

interface Vlan102

description Warehouse

nameif office

security-level 80

ip address 172.16.102.253 255.255.255.0 standby 172.16.102.252

!

interface Vlan103

nameif warehouse-cameras

security-level 60

ip address 172.16.103.253 255.255.255.0 standby 172.16.103.252

!

interface Vlan104

description Office

nameif warehouse

security-level 70

ip address 172.16.104.253 255.255.255.0 standby 172.16.104.252

!

interface Vlan105

nameif voip

security-level 50

ip address 172.16.105.253 255.255.255.0

!

interface Vlan106

nameif guest

security-level 40

ip address 172.16.106.253 255.255.255.0

!

interface Vlan109

nameif outside

security-level 0

ip address 80.xxx.xx.100 255.255.255.248 standby 80.xxx.xx.101

!

interface Vlan254

description LAN Failover Interface

!

ftp mode passive

object-group network FELTHAM-NETWORKS

network-object 172.16.2.0 255.255.255.0

network-object 172.16.3.0 255.255.255.0

network-object 172.16.4.0 255.255.255.0

network-object host 217.xxx.xxx.155

object-group network HAYES-NETWORKS

network-object 172.16.100.0 255.255.255.0

network-object 172.16.102.0 255.255.255.0

network-object 172.16.103.0 255.255.255.0

network-object 172.16.104.0 255.255.255.0

network-object host 192.168.1.253

network-object 80.xxx.xx.96 255.255.255.248

network-object 172.16.60.0 255.255.255.0

network-object 172.16.101.0 255.255.255.0

object-group network DUNSTABLE-NETWORKS

network-object 172.16.33.0 255.255.255.0

network-object host 212.xxx.xxx.3

access-list DUNSTABLE-VPN extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group DUNSTABLE-NETWORKS

access-list FELTHAM-VPN extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group FELTHAM-NETWORKS

access-list Nat0 extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group DUNSTABLE-NETWORKS

access-list Nat0 extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group FELTHAM-NETWORKS

access-list Nat0 extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group HAYES-NETWORKS

access-list Inbound extended permit icmp any interface voip

access-list outside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group DUNSTABLE-NETWORKS

access-list outside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group FELTHAM-NETWORKS

access-list outside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group HAYES-NETWORKS

access-list outside_cryptomap extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group DUNSTABLE-NETWORKS

access-list outside_cryptomap_1 extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group FELTHAM-NETWORKS

access-list office_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group DUNSTABLE-NETWORKS

access-list office_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group FELTHAM-NETWORKS

access-list office_nat0_outbound extended permit ip object-group HAYES-NETWORKS object-group HAYES-NETWORKS

pager lines 24

logging enable

logging timestamp

logging buffer-size 8192

logging buffered debugging

logging asdm informational

mtu temp-inside 1500

mtu mgmt 1500

mtu servers 1500

mtu office 1500

mtu warehouse-cameras 1500

mtu warehouse 1500

mtu voip 1500

mtu guest 1500

mtu outside 1500

ip local pool HAYES-POOL 172.16.104.25-172.16.104.50

failover

failover lan unit secondary

failover lan interface failover Vlan254

failover interface ip failover 192.168.254.9 255.255.255.252 standby 192.168.254.10

icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1

no asdm history enable

arp timeout 14400

global (outside) 1 interface

nat (temp-inside) 0 access-list Nat0

nat (temp-inside) 1 172.16.60.0 255.255.255.0

nat (servers) 0 access-list Nat0

nat (servers) 1 172.16.101.0 255.255.255.0

nat (office) 0 access-list office_nat0_outbound

nat (office) 1 172.16.102.0 255.255.255.0

nat (warehouse) 0 access-list Nat0

nat (warehouse) 1 172.16.104.0 255.255.255.0

nat (outside) 0 access-list Nat0

nat (outside) 1 172.16.101.0 255.255.255.0

route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 80.168.58.97 1

timeout xlate 3:00:00

timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02

timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00

timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00

timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute

timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00

timeout floating-conn 0:00:00

dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy

aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL

aaa authentication http console LOCAL

aaa authorization exec authentication-server

http server enable

http 172.16.33.0 255.255.255.0 warehouse

http 172.16.100.0 255.255.255.0 mgmt

http 172.16.30.0 255.255.255.0 warehouse

http 172.16.33.0 255.255.255.0 temp-inside

http 172.16.60.0 255.255.255.0 temp-inside

no snmp-server location

no snmp-server contact

snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart

sysopt noproxyarp servers

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac

crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac

crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800

crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000

crypto dynamic-map DM-HAYES 10 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA

crypto dynamic-map DM-HAYES 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 288000

crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5

crypto map CM-VPN 10 match address DUNSTABLE-VPN

crypto map CM-VPN 10 set pfs

crypto map CM-VPN 10 set peer 212.xxx.xxx.3

crypto map CM-VPN 10 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA

crypto map CM-VPN 20 match address FELTHAM-VPN

crypto map CM-VPN 20 set pfs

crypto map CM-VPN 20 set peer 217.xxx.xxx.155

crypto map CM-VPN 20 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA

crypto map CM-VPN 99 ipsec-isakmp dynamic DM-HAYES

crypto map outside_map2 10 match address outside_cryptomap_1

crypto map outside_map2 10 set pfs

crypto map outside_map2 10 set peer 217.xxx.xxx.155

crypto map outside_map2 10 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA

crypto map outside_map2 20 match address outside_cryptomap

crypto map outside_map2 20 set pfs

crypto map outside_map2 20 set peer 212.xxx.xxx.3

crypto map outside_map2 20 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA

crypto map outside_map2 interface outside

crypto isakmp enable outside

crypto isakmp policy 10

authentication pre-share

encryption aes

hash sha

group 2

lifetime 86400

telnet timeout 5

ssh scopy enable

ssh 172.16.60.0 255.255.255.0 temp-inside

ssh 172.16.100.0 255.255.255.0 mgmt

ssh 172.16.33.0 255.255.255.0 mgmt

ssh 172.16.33.0 255.255.255.0 warehouse

ssh timeout 60

ssh version 2

console timeout 0

management-access warehouse

dhcp-client update dns server both

dhcpd address 172.16.60.1-172.16.60.175 temp-inside

dhcpd dns 79.xxx.xxx.84 interface temp-inside

dhcpd domain hayes.com interface temp-inside

dhcpd enable temp-inside

!

dhcpd address 172.16.101.2-172.16.101.10 servers

dhcpd dns 79.xxx.xxx.84 interface servers

dhcpd domain hayes.com interface servers

dhcpd enable servers

!

dhcpd address 172.16.102.1-172.16.102.175 office

dhcpd dns 79.xxx.xxx.84 interface office

dhcpd domain hayes.com interface office

dhcpd enable office

!

dhcpd address 172.16.103.1-172.16.103.200 warehouse-cameras

dhcpd domain cameras.hayes.com interface warehouse-cameras

dhcpd enable warehouse-cameras

!

dhcpd address 172.16.104.1-172.16.104.175 warehouse

dhcpd dns 79.xxx.xxx.84 interface warehouse

dhcpd domain hayes.com interface warehouse

dhcpd enable warehouse

!

threat-detection basic-threat

threat-detection statistics access-list

no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept

ntp server 172.16.104.254 source warehouse

webvpn

group-policy HAYES-RAVPN-POLICY internal

group-policy HAYES-RAVPN-POLICY attributes

dns-server value 172.16.104.254 79.xxx.xxx.84

vpn-idle-timeout 1440

vpn-tunnel-protocol IPSec l2tp-ipsec

username admin password /f.QRufHe2ulQB/e encrypted privilege 15

tunnel-group HAYES type remote-access

tunnel-group HAYES general-attributes

address-pool HAYES-POOL

default-group-policy HAYES-RAVPN-POLICY

tunnel-group HAYES ipsec-attributes

pre-shared-key *

tunnel-group 212.xxx.xxx.3 type ipsec-l2l

tunnel-group 212.xxx.xxx.3 ipsec-attributes

pre-shared-key *

tunnel-group 217.xxx.xxx.155 type ipsec-l2l

tunnel-group 217.xxx.xxx.155 ipsec-attributes

pre-shared-key *

!

class-map inspection_default

match default-inspection-traffic

!

!

policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map

parameters

message-length maximum client auto

message-length maximum 512

policy-map global_policy

class inspection_default

inspect dns preset_dns_map

inspect ftp

inspect h323 h225

inspect h323 ras

inspect ip-options

inspect netbios

inspect rsh

inspect rtsp

inspect skinny

inspect esmtp

inspect sqlnet

inspect sunrpc

inspect tftp

inspect sip

inspect xdmcp

!

service-policy global_policy global

prompt hostname context

no call-home reporting anonymous

call-home

profile CiscoTAC-1

no active

destination address http someAddress://butIcantPostLinks

destination transport-method http

subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic

subscribe-to-alert-group environment

subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly

subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly

subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily

: end
```

Comment: It might help if you post the ACLs you have in place... anonymized of course.

Comment: Post your full configuration.

Comment: Please be sure to remove your password hashes from  configurations you post... It's [*extremely easy*](http://www.hope.co.nz/projects/tools/ciscopw.php) to recover the password.

Comment: What is the license on the ASA? Base config only allows 10 clients, so if you have already have 10 clients connected then the 11th won't be able to connect.  It doesn't look like you had this issue, but worth noting as this has bitten me a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that deny because you have not allowed the returning ICMP ping packet on the outside interface of the firewall. ICMP is stateless and because of this you will need to allow the traffic out and in. Something like this will fix that.

```
Access-list <OUTSIDE_ACCESSLIST-NAME> extended permit icmp any any echo
Access-list <OUTSIDE_ACCESSLIST-NAME> extended permit icmp any any echo-reply
```

Without a copy of your config I cannot tell you any more but I would say your internet access issue is NAT related. Post up the config.

Comment: Thanks your help. This has indeed solved the pinging issue. Clients with statically assigned IPs are still unable to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue with the ASA, but with the server we were testing with.
After setting the IP to static, dhclient continued to run. Upon attempting to renew the lease, it would fail and the server would lose it's network connection.

Thanks for all you help.